# Local frame of reference

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, kerr-metric

I am currently simulating particle trajectories in Kerr spacetime numerically with $M=1$ and $a=1$.

[image]

In the picture above, I am calculating the geodesic in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates. I was messing around with the simulation a little bit and I wanted to transform to a local lorentz frame by use of a vierbein (tetrad) $e^m_{\ \ \  \nu}$. The problem I encounter is that in the local lorentz frame I get velocities higher than the speed of light.

So far, I have checked that:

- $e^m_{\ \ \ \mu}e^n_{\ \ \ \nu}g^{\mu \nu}=\eta^{mn}$
- $u^\mu u_\nu = -1$

which seems to imply both that *1)* the $e^m_{\ \ \ \mu}$ is calculated correctly and *2)* that the particle is not moving faster than the speed of light.

My transformation into local frame is done via: $e^m_{\ \ \ \mu}u^\mu=u^m$

And I get the result $u^3>1$.

My question would be whether I am doing the local frame transformation incorrectly / I am missing something. The other possibility is numerical error.

Comment: What is the actual value of $u^3$?

Comment: varies by little; e.g. $u^3$ around $u^3=1.002$ or $u^3=1.01$ (with $c=1$). However, the two checks I mention there are accurate to around $0.00000000001$ digits which is why I do not suspect rounding error. In the case above the value was $u^3=1.002$.

Comment: I suppose you are aware that $u^3 > 1$ must not necessarily be wrong. As long as $u^iu_i < 0$ the velocity vector is timelike. I.e. if $|u^0| > |u^3|$ then you must not be in error. I assume then that $|u^0| \leq 1$, correct?

Comment: @ErikJörgenfelt In the local frame after conversion? I'm using ZAMO tetrads and the $u^3$ in ZAMO frame, according to at least what I seemed to read, should be one of the cartesian velocities in the local frame. I was not aware of this. I was taught that in the local lorentz frame nothing should have the velocity higher than the speed of light. Maybe my transformation is then incorrect? Sample value for 4-velocity in the local frame: $u=(1.4686090414196038001, -0.085377712814130063412, -0.22817652410017127962, 1.0475966001011713935)$ with $c=1$

Comment: Let me rephrase the above: Do you mean that $u^3>1$ is ok even in the local frame ($g_{mn}=\eta_{mn}$), as long as $u_m u^m=-1$?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I mean.

Comment: @ErikJörgenfelt Ah, alright. In that case my understanding is somewhat incorrect. Would the proper way to extract the velocity measured by ZAMO observer be $\frac{u^3}{u^0} = \frac{dz}{dt}$? What I would like to extract is the velocity of a particle measured by the ZAMO observer whose tetrad frame is given by $e^m_{\ \ \ \mu}$

Comment: @ErikJörgenfelt Oh by the way feel free to add it as the answer :)

Comment: Where is your ZAMO?  The interpretation of your coordinates will depend on where they are in the spacetime.  Is it always co-located with the test particle, but not co-moving?  Is it on it's own trajectory?

Comment: @PaulT. ZAMO frame is computed always at the particle position and it is supposed to be on its own trajectory. The reason for this is because later on I would like to have one observer look at many particles at one point in space.

Comment: @Otto I am really really hoping you are still active here. Can you advise a lost soul a bit more about how you transfer from global to local in a real simulation?? For instance, do you have a decent reference guide to do this?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin The way that I did it for Kerr was that I had a local ZAMO tetrad defined in my coordinate system. This has an analytical form. I don't have the piece of code any longer and I can't remember the source where I dug up the ZAMO tetrad, but I imagine there are quite a few sources that gives an expression for this. Then, the tetrad $e^m_\mu$ can be used to transform $u^m = e^m_\mu u^\mu$ to the local frame (i.e., in this case $u^\mu$ is the four-velocity in the 'global' frame and $u^m$ is in local frame). The tetrad satisfies $e_m^\mu e_n^\nu g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{m n}$.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin Here's a pretty good reference on tetrads in general https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/astr3740_17/grbook.pdf

Comment: @Otto that’s very helpful. I appreciate it. Since my comment I have developed code that successfully transfer between local and global frames and I’ve verified with the global and local first integrals. My next step is adding an external radial force in the local frame! Any experience with this? I’m think fermi walker is the way to go?

Comment: Hey @Rumplestillskin No experience on that, but I'd be happy to hear how it goes :)

Comment: @Otto I’ll be sure to send you the paper if I ever figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Erik_Jorgenfelt says, a timelike four velocity will have $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}=-1$.  Remember that $\vec{u}$ is proper velocity,

$$ \vec{u} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{x}}{\mathrm{d}\tau},$$

not coordinate velocity.  It's perfectly okay to have a component of proper velocity be greater than one in geometrized units as long as the vector remains timelike.

To get coordinate velocity, you can just compute (for the speed in the $\hat{e}_i$ direction):

$$ v^i = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^i}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{u^i}{u^t} = \frac{p^i}{p^t}, $$

In your case, it makes sense to use the components of the proper velocity.  You already have them in the frame of interest.  If you were dealing with a lightlike trajectory you would need to use momentum.

Another case where it is more useful to use momentum would be if you want to know the velocity of some test particle relative to the Boyer-Lindquist coordinates.  To get the velocity in the $\hat{e}_\phi$ direction, you would compute:

$$ p^\phi = g^{\phi \mu} p_\mu = g^{\phi t}p_t + g^{\phi\phi}p_\phi $$
$$ p^t = g^{\phi \mu} p_\mu = g^{t t}p_t + g^{t\phi}p_\phi $$

where $g_{\mu\nu}$ are the components of the Kerr metric in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates.

If the particle of interest is the ZAMO, then $p_\phi=0$ so $\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{g^{\phi t}}{g^{t t}}$.  This is frame-dragging.

If you carry out the momentum based process in the locally inertial ZAMO frame, the metric of interest is Minkowski.  This would simplify things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive answer both Erik & Paul. Since you mentioned the relative velocity to BL coordinates I would like to ask whether or not finding the coordinates relative to BL coordinates always works with $p^\phi=g^{\phi m}p_m$ even when the 4-momentum is in another frame with different coordinate axes. One of the things I would like to make sure is that in the local frame the tetrad axes (in this case ZAMO observer axes) are aligned with BL coordinate axes.

Comment: When dealing with component expressions like $p^\phi$, all terms must be  expressed in the same coordinate system.  If you have ZAMO momentum, you'll need to transform it to BL.  You could alternately express the Kerr metric in the local ZAMO coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement for the velocity to be timelike, i.e lower than the speed of light, is that $u^iu_i < 0$ ($u^iu_i = -1$ is desired in your case since the transformation should retain normalization, which the values given in the comments matches to the 13th decimal), regardless of the numerical value of independent components.

To extract the observed 3-velocity is more complicated and to be honest not my strong suit. I found [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0111073) paper on arxiv that might be helpful. However, at a cursory glance it seems like if you consider a single observer with a single world line the result given should depend on the choice of extension of the observer velocity, wherefore it would seem the speed can only be properly defined for an observer coincident with the test particle. Parallel transport of the observer velocity vector along the null geodesic connecting the observer and the test particle might solve this, but as I said: not my strong suit.